# how can i enter this mode using shortcuts in neovim?

Tags: terminal, editor, neovim, neovim-plugin

[image]

I accident toggle this window, but i can't know how to toggle this terminal window even after i search in Google. After some trys, I find when i enter neovim with nvchad and press `<esc>` + `<i>` I can toggle this window. But only find this :

[image]

It's really daunt me, so i come here to ask for help...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Neovim, but this looks like a TMux pop-up; and it also looks like you're in TMux — hint: green bar at the bottom.

This is the config I have in my `~/.tmux.conf` to display the pop-up

```
# pop up
# ======
bind * display-popup -E
```

Now, if I enter the sequence `<C-b> *` (i.e. `<C-b> <S-8>`), that pop-up overlays the screen.

Check for such a binding in your TMux config, using

```bash
$ tmux list-keys | grep display-popup
```

Comment: Thank you! There's a lot for me to learn...